# Enforce sub-type in array of generics

Tags: typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a list of columns where each column has constraints that I would like enforced by the type system.  A column renderer has a generic `value` property and also has a `valueGetter` that should return the appropriate type for the custom renderer.

My difficulty is that when I declare the array, I don't know what each of the types is going to be so I'm resorting to `unknown` which makes my assignment to columns not enforce types.

```
export interface Grid<R> {
    // How can I specify that the second type param should be inferred from its usage?
    columns: GridColumn<R, unknown>[];
}
```

My question is: how can I infer the type of `value` in my `GridColumn` interface

```
/**
 * R is the type of the whole record for current row
 * V is the type of `ColumnRenderer#value`
 */
export interface GridColumn<R, V> {
    renderer: ColumnRendererSpec<R, V>;
}

/** The component that will be dynamically instantiated */
export interface ColumnRenderer<V> {
    value: V;
}

interface ColumRendererConstructor<V> {
     new(...args: any[]): ColumnRenderer<V>;
}

interface ValueGetter<R,V> {
    (record: R): V
}

export interface ColumnRendererSpec<R, V> {
    type: ColumRendererConstructor<V>;

    /** Retrieves what is going to be passed to set ColumnRenderer#value  */
    valueGetter: ValueGetter<R, V>;
}

export interface Grid<R> {
    columns: GridColumn<R, unknown>[];
}
```

Here's how I'd like to call it

```
export interface Icon {
    code: string;
    label: string;
}

export interface Tooltip {
    text: string;
    tooltipText: string;
}

/** Type of record being passed to this grid */
interface MyRecord {
  code: string;
  label: string;
  text: string;
  description: string;
}

/** Renderers */
@Component({template: `<p><clr-icon icon="value.code"></clr-icon>value.label</p>`})
export class IconRenderer implements ColumnRenderer<Icon> {
    value: Icon;
}
@Component({template: `<p [title]="value.tooltipText</p>value.text`})
export class TooltipRenderer implements ColumnRenderer<Tooltip> {
    value: Tooltip;
}


const grid: Grid<MyRecord> = {
    columns: [
        {
            renderer: {
                type: IconRenderer,
                // This is compiling but shouldn't because valueGetter should return an Icon                    // 
                valueGetter: (r) => 2,
            },
        },
        {
            renderer: {
                type: TooltipRenderer,
                // This doesn't compile, but I wish I didn't have to cast
                valueGetter: (r) => 2,
            },
        } as ColumnRendererSpec<MyRecord, Tooltip>,    
    ]
};
```

As my comments in the code indicate, I'd like to enforce that `valueGetter` returns the correct type inferred from `ColumnRendererSpec#type`'s value property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the best way but, since the column renderers implement `interface ColumnRenderer<V>` and since `V` should be return type of `valueGetters`, We can pass the column renderer constructor and `valueGetter` method as parameters to a utility method that would create the renderer spec object and that would help the getter to infer its return type from the generic passed to `ColumnRenderer`.

Example:

```
  function createColumnRendererSpec<R, V>(
     ctor: ColumnRendererConstructor<V>, 
     valueGetter: (r: R) => V): ColumnRendererSpec<R, V> {
         return {
             type: ctor,
             valueGetter
         }
     }
```