# Can I create a prop that inherits another prop's generic type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a React project using TypeScript, and I want to create a new component that takes a value that is an array of objects, and can create new objects to add to this array. When creating a new object, I want it to start with a blueprint that I define, that already includes some default values for some of the object's fields.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the blueprint to follow the value's generic type. The below (very simplified example) code is perfectly fine according to TypeScript:

```
type Props<T extends object> = {
  value: Array<T>;
  blueprint: T;
};

function MyComponent<T extends object>({}: Props<T>) {
  return <div></div>;
}

function ParentComponent() {
  return <MyComponent
    value={[{ foo: "bar" }, { foo: "oof"}]}
    blueprint={{ boo: "faz" }} // This doesn't throw a type-error, but I would like it to.
  />
}
```

I'd like TypeScript to throw a type-error when the `blueprint` prop doesn't look like an object in the `value` array. I've tried doing this by using a second generic type that extends or equals the first, but I've not managed to get to a solution.

Comment: This is because TypeScript has no way to know what the infer site is for `T`. Is is supposed to use `value` or `blueprint`? Since it can't, it uses the lowest common denominator. If you look at the type that TypeScript assigns to those properties, you'll that the type of  `blueprint` and `value` are  `{foo: string;  boo?: undefined;} |  boo: string;  foo?: undefined;}` I think there may be a way to specify what the call site is, and it means creating a wrapper function, but I can't remember exactly how to do it.

Comment: You can always specify it from the caller: `return <MyComponent<{foo: string}>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the compiler will infer `T` both from the `value` property and the `blueprint` property, often as a union of the types inferred from each property.  But you want the compiler only to infer `T` from `value` and just *verify* that `blueprint` matches that.  In other words, you want the `T` in `blueprint` to be a *non-inferential type parameter usage*, as suggested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).

This feature isn't quite *officially* supported, but there are a few ways to get this behavior.  The first one is to "lower the inference priority" of the `T` in the `blueprint` property, by [intersecting it with the nearly-top type `{}`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-320754731):

```
type NoInfer<T> = T & {};

type Props<T extends object> = {
  value: Array<T>;
  blueprint: NoInfer<T>;
};
```

Another way is to [use conditional type deferral](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829#issuecomment-504042546) to prevent inference from happening:

```
type NoInfer<T> = [T][T extends any ? 0 : never];

type Props<T extends object> = {
  value: Array<T>;
  blueprint: NoInfer<T>;
};
```

In either version, `blueprint` eventually is evaluated as being type `T` (or nearly `T`) but the inference is either delayed or prevented there.  Both versions give you the following behavior for your example:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  return <MyComponent
    value={[{ foo: "bar" }, { foo: "oof" }]}
    blueprint={{ boo: "faz" }} // error!
  // Type '{ boo: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ foo: string; }'.
  />
}
```

which is what you wanted.

---

Not sure it's worth doing these workarounds as they may have some observable issues or edge cases in a wider code base.  That's probably up to you to decide how badly your use case requires a no-infer.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=1&ts=3.9.2#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)

Comment: Ha, that's what I couldn't remember, (`T & {}`) forces it not to be infer site, much simpler than what I suggested

Answer (score 1):

This is because TypeScript has no way to know what the infer site is for `T`. So it finds the lowest common denominator in both usages. In your case, Typescript considers your `T` to be

```
{foo: string;  boo?: undefined;} |  {boo: string;  foo?: undefined;}
```

The simplest solution is to specify in your call what type to use:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  // does not compile
  return <MyComponent<{foo: string}>
    value={[{ foo: "bar" }, { foo: "oof"}]}
  />
}
```

If you really would like to not have to specify the params from the caller, you'd need some witchcraft to tell the compiler where `T` is supposed to get its type from. You'd need a helper function that returns another function to generate your `Props`. This way, Typescript knows that the parameter passed to the first function is the infer site.

```
function getProps<T extends object>(value: T[]): (blueprint: T) => Props<T> {
   return function(blueprint: T) {
     return {
       value,
       blueprint
     };
   }
}

const doesCompile = getProps([{a: 1}])({a:2});
const doesNotCompile = getProps([{a: 1}])({b: 2});

function ParentComponentWithFunctionCallCompiles() {
  const props = getProps([{a: 2}])({a: 1});
  return <MyComponent {...props} />
}

function ParentComponentWithFunctionCallDoesNotCompile() {
  const props = getProps([{a: 2}])({b: 1});
  return <MyComponent {...props} />
}
```

You can [play with this on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-infer-types-specify-call-site?file=index.tsx)

I've also asked a similar question before. See [Enforce sub-type in array of generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205715/enforce-sub-type-in-array-of-generics). I decided to answer this question instead of just marking it a dupe because it does require a lot of grokking before understanding it. At least it did for me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I actually kind of liked your first solution where you specify the type of the generic. Since in my project the incoming values are already typed, this would have been a fairly simple and robust solution.The only downside would have been that the component in question is used in a lot of places, so I would have to add it to each one, and make the code slightly less readable (imo).

I ended up going with the NoInfer solution from the accepted answer, but if I ever run into trouble with that, I'll definitely come back to your solution!